# In emacs batch mode, how to evaluate/tangle a named source block in an org-mode file?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, batch-mode

I have a org-mode file (test.org) as below:

```
#+NAME: my-tangle-to-file
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :tangle my_tangle_file.sh :dir /tmp :shebang "#!/usr/bin/env bash"
  me=$(basename $(test -L "$0" && readlink "$0" || echo "$0"))
  echo "I was tangled to a file (${me})"
#+END_SRC
```

How could I tangle/evaluate the source block `my-tangle-to-file` in batch mode?

Answer (score 2):

Does the instructions at http://orgmode.org/manual/Batch-execution.html do what you want?

Comment: My situation is a little bit complicated. I use emacs-starter-kit to management my setup and I use some home-made functions in the source block header. It seems the `emacs --batch` can't pick my setup. End up with emacs complains about can't find those home-made functions.

Comment: I see - I'm sorry I don't have a good solution for you at the moment.